# Eclipse Oxygen.2 + DBeaver - error opening ER Diagram

Tags: mysql, eclipse, database-design, eclipse-oxygen, dbeaver

I have installed latest stable Eclipse PDT and DBeaver. All work fine in DBeaver except one thing - when clicking ER Diagrams for database or table following errors appear.

First error:

[image: first error]

Second, after clicking ok in first error dialog:

[image: second, after clicking ok in first error dialog]

[Part of error log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26516953/)

If this impossible to fix, is there a db graphical design plugin that works with MySQL and all its types and features - both ways, from database to diagram, and alter database when diagram changed. I have read in DBeaver wiki it works only one direction - from database to ER diagram.

It's not about to discussion or opinion, it just difficult to find something good (stable, not outdated, for latest Oxygen Eclipse, not difficult to install and use), without trying lots of software.

**Update:**
Reported on github, developer add flags *bug*, *can`t reproduce*. Will wait and see. For now, I use MySQL Workbench, its better on visual design as working both ways - editing visual design change database, and opposite - get visual design from existing database. Some issues on exporting diagram. Still interested in Eclipse plugin doing the same.

Comment: Make sure your graphics card driver is up to date. If the error still occurs, report it to [DBeaver](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues).

Comment: driver is latest proprietary from NVideo